# How do I create a header with a half-page background (like the Twitter bootstrap Carousel theme)?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, titles

I'd like to create a LaTeX document with a half-page background, such as that in Twitter/Bootstrap's [Carousel theme](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/).  The background doesn't necessarily need a gradient like in the example (although it would be nice if it did).

How would I make a custom title (and sub-title) that follows the Carousel theme? as in it would be in a sans-serif font (e.g. Arial or Helvetica), and roughly the same font size.  Note that I am not interested for the entire page to be a title.

**Edit**: I'm trying to include a sample 'use case', described as follows

First, a gradient is created using ImageMagick as follows:

```
convert -size 800x200 xc: -channel G \
        -fx '0.3+0.2*sin(pi*(i/w))' \
        -separate gradient_fx_cos.jpg
```

I have managed to get up to the following stage in my LaTeX file (clearly the bounding box is wrong, and I have not been able to set a top margin for the second column):

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\renewcommand*\sfdefault{phv}  % Sans-Serif defaults to Helvetica

\usepackage[
  paper=a4paper,
  top=2.5cm,
  left=2.5cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  bottom=2cm
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[bb=4cm 0 13cm 4cm, width=\textwidth]{gradient_fx_cos.jpg}
\end{figure}

\vspace{-7cm}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
  {\fontfamily{phv}
   \fontseries{b}
   \fontsize{40}{42}
   \selectfont\color{white}
   LaTeX Document Template\\
  }
  \vspace{0.7cm}
  {\fontfamily{phv}
   \fontseries{m}
   \fontsize{28}{30}
   \selectfont\color{white}
   Nathaniel Ng
  }
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2.5cm}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Abstract}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]

\section{Methods}
\lipsum[5-9]

\section{Discussion}
\lipsum[10-15]

\section{Conclusion}
\lipsum[16-17]

\end{document}
```

The resulting image (using pdfLaTeX) is as shown:

[image: first page]

How do I center the image, and how do I set the margins (for the just the first page) correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer:  The solution below is appropriate only for the title page.  It can probably be adapted to be a header though.*

This solution uses [Ti*k*Z](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) in order to place a gray rectangle at the top of the page.  Ti*k*Z also allows you to have a shading if you want, just have a look through its manual (in particular, the *Shadings Library* section) to find how to do it.  It should be easy enough to adapt the code I have below.

For the font, I use [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) and compile it with LuaLaTeX.  This allows you to use system fonts in addition to the usual fonts defined through LaTeX packages.  The following example uses [Roboto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roboto) and [EB Garamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garamond#EB_Garamond) which are both free fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  hmargin=2cm,
  vmargin=2cm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  BoldFont={Roboto},
]{Roboto Light}
\newfontfamily\ebgfamily{EB Garamond}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tikz [remember picture, overlay] 
      \fill [gray] 
            (current page.north east) rectangle ($(current page.north west) + (0, -5cm)$);

\vspace{-1cm} 

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont
  \color{white} \bfseries
  Nathanial Ng
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  \flushright
  \fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont
  \color{white}
  Question Asker \\
  StackExchange 
\end{minipage}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{center}
  \color{white} \ebgfamily \itshape \fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont
  If you try to fail, and succeed, which have you done?
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that due to the head taking up some space, the normal text immediately following the header has a change of actually ending up inside the header.  This can be easily rectified with a `\vspace{<distance>}` which inserts the appropriate vertical space.  In the above case, `\vspace{2cm}` seems like a good amount.

### Two Column Case

In the two column case, you won't be able to use `\vpsace` as shown above to make sure the text doesn't run into the header (as noted in the OP edit).  Also, the minipages do not work as they should.

One way to get around the first issue that is two use `\twocolumn[\vspace{<distance>}]` which inserts the given text (or whitespace in this case) at the top of a new page across both columns.

As for the issue with the minipages, this is solved by putting the text in Ti*k*Z nodes, and placing these nodes absolutely on the page:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[
  hmargin=2cm,
  vmargin=2cm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  BoldFont={Roboto},
]{Roboto Light}
\newfontfamily\ebgfamily{EB Garamond}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\twocolumn[\vspace{4cm}]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \fill [gray] 
        (current page.north east) rectangle ($(current page.north west) + (0, -5cm)$);
  \node [anchor=north west, font=\fontsize{40}{40}\bfseries\color{white}]
        at ($(current page.north west) + (2cm, -1.5cm)$)
        {Nathanial Ng};
  \node [anchor=north east, align=right, font=\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont\color{white}]
        at ($(current page.north east) + (-2cm, -1.5cm)$)
        {Question Asker \\ StackExchange};
  \node [anchor=south, font=\fontsize{15}{15}\color{white}\ebgfamily\itshape]
        at ($(current page.north) + (0, -4.5cm)$)
        {If you try to fail, and succeed, which have you done?};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{-1cm}
\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image: output twocolumn]

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I don't have Roboto on my system, however I realise I don't need fancy fonts--\fontfamily{phi} for Helvetica is sufficient.  Still, the problem I run into with this solution is the page margins--add "\lipsum[1-10]" to the bottom of your solution (with the \lipsum package) and you'll see what I mean.  It's even worse with double column pages: e.g. \documentclass[twocolumn]{article} or \documentclass[twocolumn]{scrarctl}. -Nathaniel

Comment: @nathanielng Without knowing further your use-case, it is difficult to adjust accordingly.  Feel free to edit the question and describe more exactly what you need.  I adjusted the answer to mention how you can fix the paragraph text running into the header.  You can't use my solution with the `twocolumn` option without doing some more adjustments (in particular, you'll need to place the text in Ti*k*Z instead of being inside a minipage); however, you can emulate the two column behaviour with the `multicol` package by placing the body text inside `\begin{multicols}{2} ... \end{multicols}`.

Comment: thanks for your inputs--I've managed to make some further progress, as well as to make it into a "use-case". I've also added some sample code (via ImageMagick) to create a gradient background (note that in future, I may wish to choose to replace the image with something else). The two problems remaining are the centering and the margins.

Comment: @nathanielng I updated the answer to address the issue with the two-column layout.  Also, you can create shadings within Ti*k*Z itself.  Just replace `\fill` with `\shade` in the above example and have a read of the Ti*k*Z manual to find out how to customize the shading further.

Comment: Thanks, it works.  I think the key point was "\twocolumn[\vspace{4cm}]".